Why does constrOptim in R find suboptimal solution at certain constraints?
I am using constrOptim to find the optimal allocation of a budget between two inputs to produce the highest benefit.
I assume the optimal allocation would result in the marginal benefit of the two inputs to be equal. However, at certain budgets and benefit functions, this is not the case.
Example:
#Define the benefit functions
benefit_c <- function(x){
  1832283199  + 162.1422 * x - 6.8976 * x *log(x)
}

benefit_m <- function(x){
  303009100 + 100.593 * x - 4.486285 * x *log(x)
}

# Corresponding marginal benefit functions
marg_c <- function(x){
  (162.1422- 6.8976)  - 6.8976 *log(x)
}

marg_m <- function(x) {
  (100.593- 4.486285)  - 4.486285  * log(x)
}

# Total benefit function
benefit_function <- function(x) {
  c <- x[1] 
  m <- x[2] 
  
  ben_func <- - (benefit_c(c) + benefit_m(m))
  names(ben_func) <- "tot_benefit"
  
  return(ben_func)
}

# Set parameters
# Budget
budget <- 2.5e9

# Initial starting points
eps <- .Machine$longdouble.eps # low number, but avoid zero due to logs
init_pars <- c(0.1, 0.1) # starting values

# Constraint matrices
constr_input_matrix <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,-1,-1),
                              nrow = 3,ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE)
constr_output_matrix <- matrix(c(eps,eps,-budget),
                               nrow = 3,ncol = 1,byrow = TRUE)

# Run solver
log_solution <- constrOptim(theta = init_pars,
                            f = benefit_function,
                            grad = NULL,
                            ui = constr_input_matrix,
                            ci = constr_output_matrix,
                            control = list(reltol = eps) # sets a value for tolerance acceptable solution precision
)



# Find marginal benefits, should be equal
marg_c(log_solution$par[1])

marg_m(log_solution$par[2])

The resulting marginal benefits are 7.16 and 7.33, respectively.
Oddly, if I set the budget to 2.4e9 or 2.6e9, I do get equal marginal benefits (7.46 and 6.95 respectively). Hence it seems it may be an issue of precision or tolerance, but I have not been able to correct it.
What is the cause of this and how to adjust for it?

Mathematically, I don't think you have any issues in the solution of your optimization problem, when you observed equal marginal benefits. This is due to the possibility of meeting the  Karush–Kuhn–Tucker (KKT) conditions when attempting to approach the optimal solution. So, it is NOT weird you see identical marginal benefits, sometimes.

A few facts that you should be aware of:

Your marginal benefit functions marg_c and marg_m, are indeed the first derivatives of your benefit functions benefit_c and benefit_m, respectively (I believe you can manually derive them with your calculus knowledge). In other words, the partial derivatives of the total benefits  benefit(x1,x2), with respect to x1 and x2, are marg_c(x1) and marg_m(x2), respectively.

In your optimization problem, you have constraints x1+x2 <= budget, x1 >=0  and x2 >= 0, where slack variables will be introduced and discussed how the KKT conditions can be meet. It is possible in one situation that, the optimal x1* and x2* are achieved when marg_c(x1*)==marg_m(x2*)==C, where C is a constant depending on the slack variables. Probably you can refer to some examples here for easier understanding.



Thank you, I am not sure I comprehend the significance of this. From an economics background, I used Lagrangians to find constrained optimums where it would always be the case that marginal profits/benefits were equal - which is the outcome I would want here. Is the current outcome unavoidable when using inequalities? Can I force equal marginal benefits in any way?

@Modern_ibex I don't think it is avoidable since the solved optimums depends on the budget, which determines the marginal benefits in turn. You can try budget <- 1 as an extreme case to see the difference in marginal benefits.

But is the solution above actually an optimum? If I reassign a value from input c to m I can get higher benefits than the solution. That is -benefit_function(c(log_solution$par[1] - 1e6,  log_solution$par[2] + 1e6)) > - log_solution$value for this budget value.

Through trial and error, I've found that adjusting the inputs by around 1.193e7 yields a far better outcome, adding around 1.03 million in benefits and equal marginal benefits of 7.20 for both inputs. Hence the computed solution is not actually an optimum as far as I can see.
